# What can we infer about heavy dark matter?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, dark-matter, machos

Until recently, most of the ideas regarding the nature of dark matter revolved around WIMPs.  Now that the LHC has not turned up any evidence of SUSY, people are starting to earnestly look towards other options, especially the axion and other light scalar (or possibly vector) particles.  People have proposed lots of ways to look for such particles, and many such experiments (e.g. ADMX and CASPEr) are currently underway.

On the other end of the mass spectrum are the [MACHOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_compact_halo_object), and astronomical observations (looking for microlensing effects, as described on the wikipedia page) can rule these out in certain mass ranges as comprising dark matter.

I'm interested in what can be said about dark matter that is heavy, but not as heavy as MACHOs.  In particular, it seems to me that we should be able to rule out dark matter in certain mass ranges based on the following observations:

1. In analogy to the microlensing searches for MACHOs, I expect that sufficiently heavy, low density dark matter particles would produce detectable, transient signals in gravity sensors, such as torsion pendula.  (This is also akin to searches for domain walls in DM fields.)
2. If dark matter were heavy and thermal, it would presumably clump near the centers of stars and planets, which would be detectable via e.g. lensing effects.

So my question is the following: What limits, if any, can observations like those above place on allowed masses of dark matter particles?

Comment: http://arxiv.org:443/find/grp_physics/1/AND+AND+abs:+mass+ti:+AND+dark+matter+ti:+limit/0/1/0/past/0/1

I suggest perusal of these papers

Comment: Does PDG (http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/mobile/reviews/pdf/rpp2015-rev-dark-matter.pdf) or Bertone (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0404175) say anything?

Comment: There's an extremely recent paper about this, at arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03947.pdf , which suggests a non-particulate form of dark matter might resolve the currently-frenetic search to resolve our inability to find Weakly-Interacting Massive Particles: I hope someone more knowledgeable than myself might be able to post or edit something making this new proposal easier to picture.  (Best I can do is "We're in a dark matter particle of a larger and older universe", but it's a stretch.)